# Creating PowerPoint presentations programmatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office, powerpoint

Is there a way to programmatically create PowerPoint presentations in asp.net? If possible, I'd like to use C# and create PowerPoint 2007 presentations with out install Office on server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PowerPoint 2007 presentation files are really ZIP files that contain XML and other resources.  The other answer has a few links to more info, but the short answer is "Yes, you can, at least in theory, create PowerPoint 2007 presentations."  Fairly steep learning curve, though, I'd imagine.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid that you cant create ppt without having powerpoint installed, as com will be used to do that. if the file type is not the constraint then the best bet will be using html5 with jquery, you can achive the same (nearly same) effects etc as with ppt but the learning curve can be a problem if you are new to html5 and jquery.